# TeamCity build configuration trigger set to wait for composite build completition does not trigger

Tags: teamcity

I have a configuration that is composite and it's currently at the end of the build chain and is triggered by github VCS trigger.

Let's imagine I have this build chain:

```
build A \
build B - composite build
build C /
```

Then I want to have configuration D that is just running custom powershell script, does not need any snapshot dependencies and should run after after the composite build finishes:

```
build A \
build B - Composite build - build D
build C /
```

I've created build D and set up the trigger to wait for Composite build to finish (even after it fails).
But the configuration D is never triggered. Why not?

If I alter the build chain, for example to be like this:

```
build A \ 
build B - Composite build
        /
build C  
        \ build D
```

Then the build D is triggered correctly but is not at the end of the chain and this will cause problems in the powershell step.

I also tried to setup snapshot dependency of build D and add Composite build. This works but it messes up the build chain Dependencies view where I can't see neither Timeline or List and the chain consist only of Composite and Build D.